# 2 seconds to do TLS key setup, penalizing speed to perform REST request

Tags: micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

I use a raspPy-Pico-W (Wireless) to send a HTTPS REST request to a network connected device.

The request takes ~130 ms on Postman, but ~3000 ms from RaspPy-Pico.

As the aim is to be "realtime", 3 sec is long to wait to have the requested action be performed.

A Wireshark network trace shows 2 sec between server message (line 149) and the associated response from the raspPy-pico (line 151) due I guess to the setup of the TLSv1.2 crypted chanel between systems.

Is that normal such a 2 secs for raspPy-pico-W ? I know crypto is heavy computation, but 2 sec for a 125 MHz system seems to be a very long time

Thanks for thoughts

[image: Packets of the communication]

192.168.137.248 is the raspPy-pico-W

192.168.0.24 is the REST Server

The screen shot contains all packets of the entire communication

Answer (score 0):

Found the following post on rasppi forum discussing this behavior

https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=362979